# Unexpected behavior of if statement in OCaml

Tags: if-statement, ocaml

I am learning OCaml so maybe I am writing this if-statement wrong, but for this statement:

# if 0.3 -. 0.2 = 0.1 then ’a’ else ’b’;;

the output is:

- : char = 'b'

Shouldn't the output be 'a', since 0.3 - 0.2 = 0.1?
The behavior is also the same when I write == instead of =.

Comment: there is a `.` after the `-` in `0.3 -. 0.2` is that intended?

Comment: if I run your code in https://try.ocamlpro.com/ I get a ` Syntax error` because of that `.`. If I remove it and run it again with: `if 0.3 - 0.2 = 0.1 then 'a' else 'b';;` it will return a `Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int`. so that `.` is definitely not intended there :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the posted code, though it should be using ordinary ASCII single quotes. The problem is with the approximate nature of floating values. The `.` after `-` is required in OCaml to subtract floating values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point values can only represent decimal fractions approximately. So `0.3 -. 0.2` is very close to `0.1`, but not exactly equal.

```
# 0.3 -. 0.2;;
- : float = 0.0999999999999999778
```

Understanding this is a rite of passage for programmers. Here's a site I found with some discussion: [What Every Programmer Should Know about Floating Point](https://floating-point-gui.de).

As a side comment, you should never be using the `==` (physical equality) operator in ordinary computations. Example:

```
# 1.0 == 1.0;;
- : bool = false
```

This is a different problem. Floating values aren't *that* approximate :-)

The everyday, workhorse equality comparison operator is `=`. That's what you should use unless you have a specific reason not to.